# Call Logs from IOS Version8.3 using c#

Tags: ios, icloud, calllog, ios8.3

I need to get Call Logs from I-cloud of IOS Version 8.3 where I am able get the Call Logs of Previous Version, It will be great help If Somebody Help me knows the difference between IOS Version 8.3 and Previous one with reference to the Call Logs.

using URL: "WirelessDomain#Library/CallHistory/call_history.db"